# Create table with each customer and each hour of the month

Tags: sql

I have a list of customers that we can receive calls for each month. I generate a list with a simple

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(Campaign) 
 FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(MM,TimeStamp,GETDATE()) <= 12
```

I also have short little recursion query I can use to create an entry for each hour of the current month

```
WITH time_CTE 
AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS [DateTime]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime])
    FROM time_CTE
    WHERE dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]) < EOMONTH(GETDATE())
    )
SELECT *
FROM time_CTE
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

I also have a query that will show me the total calls received for each client, for each hour of the month

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
        DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
        Timestamp)), 0)  as RoundedToHour,
    Campaign,
    COUNT(*) AS Actual

FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, Timestamp, GETDATE()) = 1
    AND Call_Type = 'Inbound'

GROUP BY Campaign,
    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0,
        DATEADD(minute, 30 - DATEPART(minute, Timestamp + '00:30:00.000'),
        Timestamp)), 0)
```

My ultimate goal is to have a procedure I can run at the beginning of each month that will update a table and add a 4 week average for each client, for each hour of the month. I have the 3 basic parts above I believe, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to add it all together properly.

My first attempt was to create a table that simply had a row for each hour of the month, for each client that we can get calls for.

```
DECLARE @date DateTime SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1))
DECLARE @comp varchar SELECT DISTINCT(Campaign) FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MM,TimeStamp,GETDATE()) <= 12

WHILE @date < EOMONTH(GETDATE())

BEGIN
    WITH time_CTE ([DateTime],Comp)
    AS 
    (
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0) AS [DateTime],
    @comp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]),
    @comp
    FROM time_CTE
    WHERE dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]) < EOMONTH(@date)
    )
        SELECT *
        FROM time_CTE
        OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
    SET @date = @date +1;
END;
```

However this did practically nothing. I understand SQL pretty well, but I have never had to do a For Loop in SQL before, and I just can't wrap my head around how to structure this to make it work.

The end table would hopefully look like this;

```
DateTime            Campaign        Avg
1/1/2021 00:00      Client 1        4
1/1/2021 00:00      Client 2        0
1/1/2021 01:00      Client 1        2
1/1/2021 01:00      Client 2        1
etc....
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT Campaign FROM ...` to make the code clearer.

Comment: I actually was not aware of that. Noted for futures reference as well. Appreciate it.

Comment: Look up summary tables. Maybe your database supports them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work with the following, which will create a row for each hour of the month, for each client that has calls.

```
 DECLARE @CompTable TABLE (comp varchar(max))

 INSERT INTO @CompTable
     SELECT DISTINCT Campaign 
     FROM [Reporting].[dbo].[New_Five9_CallLog] 
     WHERE DATEDIFF(MM,TimeStamp,GETDATE()) <= 12

 DECLARE @comp varchar(max)

 WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CompTable)
 BEGIN
      SELECT TOP 1 @comp = comp FROM @CompTable; 

     WITH Time_CTE ([DateTime])
     AS (
         SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS [DateTime]
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime])
         FROM time_CTE
         WHERE dateadd(hour, 1, [DateTime]) < EOMONTH(GETDATE())
        )
     SELECT *,
         (Select TOP 1 @comp  
         FROM @CompTable) AS Campaign
     FROM time_CTE
     OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

     DELETE FROM @CompTable WHERE comp = @comp 
 END
```